# How can I get two numbers that are written in a single line - is there a Split() method?

Tags: java, split

I want to ask the user for input in console. He'll be writing down two numbers separated by a single space.

In Java is there something like the C# Split() method I can use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: [String.split](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Note that it takes a regex as the parameter though. Alternatively you could use a [`StringTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) or a [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: It does take regex, but `String.split(" ")` would work fine in his case.

Comment: @webdestroya: Yup, it was more as a warning for future changes. In particular, trying to split on "." is likely to catch out more than a few unwary devs :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a **split()** method in **String** class.

```
String.split();
```